# Field of the form $\{a+bi|a,b\in \mathbb{F}_p\}$

Tags: field-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Artin, Algebra, Chapter 3, Ex 1.11

Consider whether the set of symbols $\{a+bi|a,b\in\mathbb{F}_p\}$ forms a field, if the laws of composition are made to mimic addition and multiplication of complex umbers.

I think it suffices to check that inverse exist.

So consider $a+ib\ne0$ and let its inverse be $c+id$, i.e.,
$$(a+ib)(c+id)=1$$
So we have
$$ac-bd+i(ad+bc)=1$$
Therefore
$$\left\{\begin{array}{c}ac-bd=1 \\ ad+bc=0 \end{array}\right.$$

Hence
$$ad=-bc$$

From the first equation we have
$$a^2c-b(ad)=a$$
$$\implies (a^2+b^2)c=a$$

Now, if $p$ is a Pythagorean prime, we can choose $a,b$ so that $p=a^2+b^2$, and this shows that the inverse doesn't exist.

Is my conclusion correct?

Besides, if $p$ is not a Pythagorean prime, does the definition given at the beginning always defines a field?

Comment: What is a Pythagorean prime? Anyway, yes, it's a field if and only if there's no $a,b$ such that $p=a^2+b^2$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Do you have any reference for the proof of the "if" part?

Comment: If $p=r^2+s^2$ then $(r/s)^2=-1$ in the field, so the equation $x^2=-1$ would be a quadratic with four solutions, $\pm(r/s)$ and $\pm i$. But a polynomial of degree $d$ can't have more than $d$ roots in a field.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks! But I've already proved the "only if" part. What I what to prove now is that if there doesn't not exists $a,b$ such that $p = a^2+b^2$, then it is a field.

Comment: Sorry. If there's no $a,b$, then $x^2+1=0$ has no solution in $F_p$, so $F_p[x]/(x^2+1)=\{a+bi\}$ is a field.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks! Can you put it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Actually, I slipped a bit there. If $a^2+b^2=p$ has no solution, then it isn't obvious that $a^2+b^2\equiv0\bmod p$ has no solution, and that's what I really need to conclude that $x^2+1=0$ has no solution in $F_p$. But it's true, anyway, and it's in lots of intro Number Theory texts, and probably all over the web, as well. I don't know whether I'll find the time to write up an answer. You may find it has already been done at question 1187050.